# Adding web reference

Tags: .net, asmx

While right clicking on the reference in the solution explorer "add webreference is missing" Why it was missing in my machine?

Answer (score 2):

Try "Add Service Reference" -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add the web reference is to click on the Project in the Solution Explorer then go to the "Project" menu and then select "Add Web Reference".